# Session Ending event not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-7

I want to let the user decides if he wants to do a last request at my app when the the Windows is shutting down or logging off. So I am using the "SessionEnding" event.

The following code is triggered but doesn't work. Here is the simplest example:

```
public App()
{
        this.SessionEnding += App_SessionEnding;
}

void App_SessionEnding(object sender, SessionEndingCancelEventArgs e)
{
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

I am afraid that I've used a boost program before in my computer (like CCleaner), and somehow it deactivated this event. =O

When I add a MessageBox to the event, and I request to log off my computer, then the MessageBox appears, but I don't have time to click somewhere because after 1 second, the system log off. The system seems to not be waiting for my application.

Obs: I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Is this the code you have in your program, or do you have a MessageBox in your ACTUAL code?

Comment: that code above is the simplest example. But I also tried to call MessageBox.Show() before the "e.Cancel = true". It showed but the system kept shutting down.

Comment: Try the code you have posted, see if it works. Windows SHOULDN'T wait for your MessageBox to return a result. I know I would be pissed off if it did.

Comment: I did try the code that I've posted. It did NOT work =D.

Comment: I am fighting with same problem. It seems that windows just kills the app if it is taking too long and there is something awaited in async part.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a sample of your code without success ... however I put this into my main window that causes the application to close and the MessageBox was displayed indefinitely until I clicked close. Could this help?

```
protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Blah", "Blah", MessageBoxButton.OK);

        base.OnClosing(e);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. I will think about it.

Comment: nah, It didn't work =/. I ran the app and logged off at Windows, and it didn't work. The system simpled logged out without waiting anything.

Comment: do you have a separate login window to the main. The code should be in the window that closes the application

Comment: did you mean that u made it work when I click "log off" at Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the event handler that's already there.

https://wpf.2000things.com/2011/01/25/197-override-application-class-methods-for-standard-events/

> ```
> public partial class App : Application
> {
>         protected override void OnSessionEnding(SessionEndingCancelEventArgs e)
>         {
>             // Always call method in base class, so that the event gets raised.
>             base.OnSessionEnding(e);
>
>             // Place your own SessionEnding logic here
>         }
> }
> ```